Temporary desktop blackout
we are using in company Lenovo T16 notebooks which we are connecting to monitors via Lenovo docking stations.
Recently, I got called several times regarding "Temporary blackout" which occurs once or twice an hour when screen looks like it is shut down (completely black) for 2 seconds after which it comes back to normal state.
I checked all the cable connections for this computer and they are connected in a right way. What could be a cause of such computer behavior?

Most logical cause is a power fluctuation on the powergrid itself.
And by that, I don't mean the actual powergrid outside, but power supplied from the grid to the building, and the distribution onwards. To make things easier, I will refer to the local powergrid as power network from this point forward in this answer. So Power network means everything power related from the group in the circuit to all devices attached to it.
When you reach a powerdraw that is close to the limit of the circuit, it may happen that a power fluctuation in the power network occurs. Some monitors will be sensitive to this and may happen to briefly not have enough power to operate. They'll lose power for a brief second and get power again. Depending on how quickly they reconnect to the signal will determine how long the screen actually stays black. Usually monitors affected by this stay off a bit longer, and other monitors that are affected may blink so fast, you don't even notice.
Do note, not all monitors will be affected by this for the simple reason that as soon as one or more devices temporarily lose power, the rest of the devices get enough power and not have a problem at all.
To elaborate more on this weird phenomenon, I have this problem with just one monitor at home. It is a monitor from HP, a good monitor, never had a problem with it. I started adding USB devices to my computer which means my PSU draws a little bit more power and that got me to this magical limit.
I have the computer hooked up to a powerbrick, and another powerbrick is also connected to a third powerbrick that is connected to the wall. On the second powerbrick, I have a lamp that I can turn on and off.
Sometimes, when my computer draws a bit more power, if I turn on or off that light, there is just enough fluctuation for my monitor to briefly lose power. Windows will then play the disconnected and reconnected sound (the monitor always flickers first, then the sound in windows).
At some point, I replaced the monitor because I wanted a higher resolution. This time it is from AOC, and the problem went away.
With the HP monitor, the on-off would also just randomly happen every 10-20 days.
One of our customers at work experienced the same problem, and because I already had this knowledge at the time, I was able to assess the problem. They had the situation where they had mostly all the same monitors in the room, and some of them would flicker at the same time, where others wouldn't. Replacing the monitors would not fix it. I suggested the powerfluctuation issue, they got an electrician to add a second group and split the powerdraw in half, and the problem went away for them.
That said, I do know that it is possible there is a problem with the monitor or the cable, so first rule out any problem with cables by replacing/swapping them, and see if that fixes it or not. See if you can move the problem around to other monitors to rule out a defective monitor, but don't forget to also consider power draw issues, especially if you have the same type of monitor and multiple monitors are affected, but not all.

Hello, thank you for your answer. I ruled out all such conditions such as defect cable and replaced the whole docking station setup as well, but issue continued anyway. I even tried to connect the new docking station to the other laptop and monitor, on new laptop/monitor issue was not visible, but it keeps coming up when connected to the other laptop.

Could still be a power issue. You can test it by isolating it, for example take that setup home and work there for a while. If its gone, its the power itself. If not, its something with the laptop or monitor.
